# How to connect to Cloudant with an Arduino Wifi Bee

Tags: arduino, wifi, cloudant

We are trying to connect our Arduino based wifi bee (an ATmega 328P) to the Cloudant data-base.  The wifi bee uses the wiwhield library to connect to the web. We can use this to connect to cosm (xively) and post/get data. However, with cloudant, we are not able to do so, and keep getting a 503 Service unavailable request.

I think the problem is that Wishield expects an IP address to be specified, whereas Cloudant uses a DNS.. I am adding the code snippet using wishield that works just fine for GET data from weather.com, but when we modify the variables for cloudant.com, it just gives me a 503 request.

Please find the different codes:
Code snippet: GetDatafromCloudant.ino : We have just changed the IP address/port details for a cloudant GET request.

```
    /*
 * A simple sketch that uses WiServer to get the hourly weather data from LAX and prints
 * it via the Serial API
 */

#include <WiServer.h>

#define WIRELESS_MODE_INFRA 1
#define WIRELESS_MODE_ADHOC 2

// Wireless configuration parameters ----------------------------------------
unsigned char local_ip[] = {192,168,1,2};   // IP address of WiShield
unsigned char gateway_ip[] = {192,168,1,1}; // router or gateway IP address
unsigned char subnet_mask[] = {255,255,255,0};  // subnet mask for the local network
const prog_char ssid[] PROGMEM = {"BSNL_AP"};       // max 32 bytes

unsigned char security_type = 2;    // 0 - open; 1 - WEP; 2 - WPA; 3 - WPA2

// WPA/WPA2 passphrase
const prog_char security_passphrase[] PROGMEM = {"bhutoriafamily"}; // max 64 characters

// WEP 128-bit keys
// sample HEX keys
prog_uchar wep_keys[] PROGMEM = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, // Key 0
                  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Key 1
                  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Key 2
                  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00  // Key 3
                };

// setup the wireless mode
// infrastructure - connect to AP
// adhoc - connect to another WiFi device
unsigned char wireless_mode = WIRELESS_MODE_INFRA;

unsigned char ssid_len;
unsigned char security_passphrase_len;
// End of wireless configuration parameters ----------------------------------------


// Function that prints data from the server
void printData(char* data, int len) {

  // Print the data returned by the server
  // Note that the data is not null-terminated, may be broken up into smaller packets, and 
  // includes the HTTP header. 
  while (len-- > 0) {
    Serial.print(*(data++));
  } 
}


// IP Address for www.weather.gov  
//uint8 ip[] = {140,90,113,200};
uint8 ip[] = {50,23,104,75};
// A request that gets the latest METAR weather data for LAX
GETrequest getWeather(ip, 5984, "http://alfatek.cloudant.com", "/wifi/_all_docs");


void setup() {
    // Initialize WiServer (we'll pass NULL for the page serving function since we don't need to serve web pages) 
  WiServer.init(NULL);

  // Enable Serial output and ask WiServer to generate log messages (optional)
  Serial.begin(57600);
  WiServer.enableVerboseMode(true);

  // Have the processData function called when data is returned by the server
  getWeather.setReturnFunc(printData);
}


// Time (in millis) when the data should be retrieved 
long updateTime = 0;

void loop(){

  // Check if it's time to get an update
  if (millis() >= updateTime) {
    getWeather.submit();    
    // Get another update one hour from now
    updateTime += 1000 * 20 ;
  }

  // Run WiServer
  WiServer.server_task();

  delay(10);
}
```

Code snippet: GetDatafromWeather.ino: This works just fine, and we can pull data from weather.com for LA weather data..

```
/*
 * A simple sketch that uses WiServer to get the hourly weather data from LAX and prints
 * it via the Serial API
 */

#include <WiServer.h>

#define WIRELESS_MODE_INFRA 1
#define WIRELESS_MODE_ADHOC 2

// Wireless configuration parameters ----------------------------------------
unsigned char local_ip[] = {192,168,1,2};   // IP address of WiShield
unsigned char gateway_ip[] = {192,168,1,1}; // router or gateway IP address
unsigned char subnet_mask[] = {255,255,255,0};  // subnet mask for the local network
const prog_char ssid[] PROGMEM = {"BSNL_AP"};       // max 32 bytes

unsigned char security_type = 2;    // 0 - open; 1 - WEP; 2 - WPA; 3 - WPA2

// WPA/WPA2 passphrase
const prog_char security_passphrase[] PROGMEM = {"bhutoriafamily"}; // max 64 characters

// WEP 128-bit keys
// sample HEX keys
prog_uchar wep_keys[] PROGMEM = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, // Key 0
                  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Key 1
                  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Key 2
                  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00  // Key 3
                };

// setup the wireless mode
// infrastructure - connect to AP
// adhoc - connect to another WiFi device
unsigned char wireless_mode = WIRELESS_MODE_INFRA;

unsigned char ssid_len;
unsigned char security_passphrase_len;
// End of wireless configuration parameters ----------------------------------------


// Function that prints data from the server
void printData(char* data, int len) {

  // Print the data returned by the server
  // Note that the data is not null-terminated, may be broken up into smaller packets, and 
  // includes the HTTP header. 
  while (len-- > 0) {
    Serial.print(*(data++));
  } 
}


// IP Address for www.weather.gov  
uint8 ip[] = {140,90,113,200};

// A request that gets the latest METAR weather data for LAX
GETrequest getWeather(ip, 80, "www.weather.gov", "/data/METAR/KLAX.1.txt");


void setup() {
    // Initialize WiServer (we'll pass NULL for the page serving function since we don't need to serve web pages) 
  WiServer.init(NULL);

  // Enable Serial output and ask WiServer to generate log messages (optional)
  Serial.begin(57600);
  WiServer.enableVerboseMode(true);

  // Have the processData function called when data is returned by the server
  getWeather.setReturnFunc(printData);
}


// Time (in millis) when the data should be retrieved 
long updateTime = 0;

void loop(){

  // Check if it's time to get an update
  if (millis() >= updateTime) {
    getWeather.submit();    
    // Get another update one hour from now
    updateTime += 1000 * 20 ;
  }

  // Run WiServer
  WiServer.server_task();

  delay(10);
}
```

Comment: You should post the code that generates the request that gives you the 503. From what you describe, I can only guess that the host header is wrong or not specified.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, Cloudant routes your request depending on the headers that are provided. You can take care of this by specifying the Host header like so: `Host: USERNAME.cloudant.com`

The 503 status code you are getting from Cloudant means that the load balancer you landed on is not aware of how to route your request because it doesn't have your account name.

You can get the IP to connect to like this (Bash terminal): `host USERNAME.cloudant.com`

However, **this is not a good idea.**

The reason that Cloudant uses DNS is so that IPs can change at the service's whim. Additionally, fail over to different load balancing servers and/or data centers is handled with DNS (local fail over within the data center is handled by the load balancers). Therefore you won't be creating a stable environment - Cloudant could, and *will*, change IPs on you thereby killing your set up.

Sorry, but it sounds like the best solution is to get DNS working in your environment.

[Source: I work at Cloudant.]